# Get contiguous Memory<byte> from ReadOnlySequence<byte>

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

After a wonderful introduction to pipes on Marc Gravell's [blog post](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) on the subject, I am tinkering with implementing pipes with sockets.

I know that Marc has already come up with [Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial)
, and I am using that as a reference, but I have a question.

It seems that `SocketAsyncEventArgs` has a new overload to the `SetBuffer()` method: `SetBuffer(Memory<byte>)`

It seems that the intent here is to integrate nicely with Pipes.

My confusion arises from the fact that `Pipe.Reader.ReadAsync()` returns a `ReadResult` containing a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` (`ReadResult.Buffer`)

In the case that `Buffer.IsSingleSegment == true`, it's fairly obvious what to do:

`SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(Buffer[0])`

But in the case where there are *multiple* segments, I'm not entirely sure what the best course of action is.

I could of course just get a `byte[]` from the pipe and be done with it, but that would incur a copy (possible more than one, even).

What is the intended use of `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` here? Is there a way to get `Memory' representing the whole contents of the sequence?

Perhaps I need to re-re-read Marc's blog post...

Comment: just mention - ReadOnlySequence doesn't have indexer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what I see:
There is this `ReadOnlySequence<>.First` which in case of `IsSingleSegment` should give you `ReadOnlyMemory<>` you are looking for.
For sequences with more segments I think you should iterate through them with

```
var iSegment = seq.Start;
ReadOnlyMemory<byte> readMemory;
while(seq.TryGet(ref iSegment, out readMemory, advance: true))
{ /* do smth */ }
```

Alternatively I think, this does the same thing:

```
foreach(var memory in seq)
{ /* do smth */ }
```

It makes sense to iterate through if you care about performance and don't want to make a copy of the whole buffer (that is what .ToArray() extension method does). 
The intention IMHO was to effectively represent non-continuous buffers.
I am not sure about `Sequence<>` implementation details, but it is common in most of buffering scenarios to hold couple of small buffers(3, 2) and switch between them so to not allocate new memory unnecessarily. That is sometimes abstracted as "Circular" or "Ring" buffers.

It leads to such "sequential" memory access pattern as in `Sequence<>`.